# Getting "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" in Rails 3, jQuery, Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

When a radio button is checked, the whole form is submitted. The answers_controller (below) does update the result, so everything works, but i get the aforementioned error in the console. I realize that in my update_result.js.erb (below) nothing is assigned to the @answers variable but i have been unable to make adjustments to it for the way i am passing the values.

answers_controller:

```
  def update_result
    params[:answer].each_pair do |key,value|
      @ans = Answer.find(key.to_i)
      @ans.update_attributes(:score => value)
    end
  end
```

update_result.js.erb:

```
$("#answers").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(@answers)) %>");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the action like this:

```
def update_result
  @answers = []

  params[:answer].each_pair do |key,value|
    ans = Answer.find(key.to_i)        
    ans.update_attributes(:score => value)
    @answers << ans
  end
end
```

Change the update_result.js.erb like this:

```
$("#answers").html("#{escape_javascript(render(@answers))}");
```

Comment: thanks for giving it a shot. It still gets the same error. I am pretty sure it is because no value is assigned to @answers.

Comment: Can you post full error message that you get? Instead of render(@answers) I think you should do something like render :partial => 'partial_name' (that will output html with @answers data)

Comment: i commented out my prior code in the update_result.js.erb file. When i removed it completely, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you.